# Reference the previous Row in Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a table like the image below.

I would like to add a "count" with a condition.

If the actual row of "id_tecnico" was equal to the previous one, then + 1, else 1. Can someone help me to do this in DAX in Power Bi??

[image]

Comment: How do you define "previous"?

Comment: The actual row -1

Comment: Power BI is a database, and unlike in Excel, there are no "actual rows" in databases. For example, in your picture the first 10 rows are absolutely identical, and there is no way to tell which one is first or second etc.  You need to have a column in your table that defines row order (that is, if you sort by it, it'll arrange rows as required).

Comment: I think that you don't actually need to "add count", but you want to calculate rank within a group, which you can do like `count = RANKX(YourTableName,[id_tecnico],,1,Dense)`. See [RANKX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/rankx-function-dax) function.

Comment: You can use Power Query to add an index over a grouped data, like described here: https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/numbering-grouped-data-power-query

Comment: It was exactly this that I was looking for. Thanks for help.